# What is the 'where' behavior in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods, hash

I am trying to write a module to pass all of my tests. It looks like its an array of hashes. I am trying to figure out what the 'where' logic is? So I can attempt to write a module to pass all of the tests.

Tests:

```
require 'test/unit'

class WhereTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
def setup
 @boris   = {:name => 'Boris The Blade', :quote => "Heavy is good. Heavy is reliable. If it doesn't work you can always hit them.", :title => 'Snatch', :rank => 4}
 @charles = {:name => 'Charles De Mar', :quote => 'Go that way, really fast. If something gets in your way, turn.', :title => 'Better Off Dead', :rank => 3}
 @wolf    = {:name => 'The Wolf', :quote => 'I think fast, I talk fast and I need you guys to act fast if you wanna get out of this', :title => 'Pulp Fiction', :rank => 4}
 @glen    = {:name => 'Glengarry Glen Ross', :quote => "Put. That coffee. Down. Coffee is for closers only.",  :title => "Blake", :rank => 5}

 @fixtures = [@boris, @charles, @wolf, @glen]
end

def test_where_with_exact_match
  assert_equal [@wolf], @fixtures.where(:name => 'The Wolf')
end

def test_where_with_partial_match
  assert_equal [@charles, @glen], @fixtures.where(:title => /^B.*/)
end

def test_where_with_mutliple_exact_results
  assert_equal [@boris, @wolf], @fixtures.where(:rank => 4)
end

def test_with_with_multiple_criteria
  assert_equal [@wolf], @fixtures.where(:rank => 4, :quote => /get/)
end

def test_with_chain_calls
  assert_equal [@charles], @fixtures.where(:quote => /if/i).where(:rank => 3)
end

end
```

Comment: Unless you're using Rails, it's most likely a module you've included that extends Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look very carefully at your first test:

```
@fixtures.where(:name => 'The Wolf')
```

The `@fixtures` object is of class `Array`, and you are calling a method on it whose name is `where`.  Therefore, to get this test to pass, you have to define a method named `where` on Array or one of its parent classes.  As a first attempt, you can write this:

```
class Array
  def where(options)
  end
end
```

I think this is what you were asking.  After writing the code above, you should get a different error message from your tests.  It will be your job to write the code inside the `where` method in order to get all your tests to pass.